# Writing to external file result of shell command with Python script

Tags: python, snmp, ioexception

I'm writing a Python script which runs an SNMP script every 3 seconds and stores the value of packets received by the interface of a router within a file. However at the second iteration of the loop I get the error:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

My code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["snmpget", "*****", "IF-MIB::ifInOctets.1"],stdout=sub$
count=1
with  open("script5min.log","a") as logfile:
        while(count!=3):
                print count
                packets_received,err = p.communicate()
                logfile.write(packets_received)
                count = count +1
                time.sleep(3)
```

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are only calling the snmpget command once, before the loop. Calling `communicate()` reads all the output from that command, [according to the documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) The file handle of `p` will be closed after reading the output, so calling `communicate` again is expected to return an error.

Solution:
Move the `Popen` call into your loop, so that a new SNMP poll will take place in each iteration. The `p` object is renewed with each poll and you will be able to `communicate()` with it.

Comment: Thank you, at the end I switched to pySNMP which better supports all SNMP commands.